# Difference between ls -l , ls -ltr and ll?

Tags: command-line, ls

When i am using these commands , i am getting the same output but only order is getting changed for `ls -ltr` command.
Can anyone please tell me what is the difference between the below commands?

1. `ll`
2. `ls -l`
3. `ls -ltr`

Comment: Try typing "ls --help", your answer will be found there.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all, the mentioned commands do not generate the same output. Here are the details:

1. `ll` : There is no command like `ll`, in Ubuntu it is an alias for the command `ls -alF`. you can find it by:

   ```
   $ type ll
   ll is aliased to `ls -alF'
   ```

   - `-a` option is to show hidden files (will show `.` and `..` too)
   - `-l` option is to show the output as a long list along with various attributes e.g. permissions, file sizes, use, group, modification time etc.
   - `-F` will append one of `*/=>@|` to the entries, it is basically used to differentiate files from directories as it will append `/` to the directory entries

   Example :

   ```
   $ ll
   total 24
   drwxrwxr-x 4 chayan chayan 4096 Jun 25 13:53 ./
   drwxrwxr-x 3 chayan chayan 4096 Jun 25 13:34 ../
   drwxrwxr-x 2 chayan chayan 4096 Jun 25 13:35 data/
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 chayan chayan   88 Jun 25 13:50 filenames.txt
   ```
2. `ls -l` : As mentioned earlier `-l` will show the entries as a long list along with various attributes.

   Example:

   ```
   $ ls -l
   total 16
   drwxrwxr-x 2 chayan chayan 4096 Jun 25 13:35 data
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 chayan chayan   88 Jun 25 13:50 filenames.txt
   ```
3. `ls -ltr` :

   - `-t` option will sort the entries by modification date (with newest first)
   - `-r` will reverse the sorting order.

   As `-t` will sort by modification time with newest first, `-r` will cause the reverse i.e. oldest entries will be shown first now.

   Example (Adding a file and a directory to make it clearer) :

   ```
   $ ls -lt
   total 16
   drwxrwxr-x 2 chayan chayan 4096 Jun 25 13:50 log
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 chayan chayan   88 Jun 25 13:50 filenames.txt
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 chayan chayan  208 Jun 25 13:49 move.sh
   drwxrwxr-x 2 chayan chayan 4096 Jun 25 13:35 data

   $ ls -ltr
   total 16
   drwxrwxr-x 2 chayan chayan 4096 Jun 25 13:35 data
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 chayan chayan  208 Jun 25 13:49 move.sh
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 chayan chayan   88 Jun 25 13:50 filenames.txt
   drwxrwxr-x 2 chayan chayan 4096 Jun 25 13:50 log
   ```

Check `man ls` to get more idea.