# What is the difference between -l and -lt

Tags: command-line, ls

I tried the command **"ls -l"** and **"ls -lt"** in the same directory, But it shows me the same output.
Do they have any difference?

Comment: Related: [Difference between ls -l , ls -ltr and ll?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640746/difference-between-ls-l-ls-ltr-and-ll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man ls`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).  Sort entries 
       alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort is specified.
.
.
.
  -t     sort by modification time, newest first
```

So the difference is that the sort is alphabetical with `ls -l`, and by modification time with `ls -lt`